# Login doesn't work - Register works fine

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to get a simple login page, user inputs their details and goes to the main.php page.

Here's the code http://pastebin.com/M4LZdcBt

Steps

-Go to localhost/game
-Enter username/password from database
-I would like to go to the main page I have set up
-Instead I get the error message "You need to be logged in to view this page!" which is set to show if the user doesn't have a session, but the code says it should give them a session?

Here is validation code, it is on my main.php page

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
echo "You must be logged in to view this page!";
}else{
?>
```

Comment: You need to show your code.  What you have here is not helpful at all.

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult for me to input so much on here

Comment: @RyanMcKenna - the code in your pastebin doesn't include `You need to be logged in to view this page`. How are you validating the session?

Comment: sorry for late reply, added code to OP

Comment: @RyanMcKenna - thanks for updating the question. Now - you're checking to see if `$_SESSION['uid']` is set; but your code isn't setting that, just `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: That's working, as well as solved a few other problems I've been having, weirdly. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER BY ANDREWSI

@RyanMcKenna - thanks for updating the question. Now - you're checking to see if $_SESSION['uid'] is set; but your code isn't setting that, just $_SESSION['username'] –  andrewsi 15 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
```

`AND` does not exist in this case, so your code will never go through. Instead; use `&&`

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
```

EDIT: `$_SESSION['uid']` doesn't exist in your code, try changing this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
echo "You must be logged in to view this page!";
}else{
```

into this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo "You must be logged in to view this page!";
}else{
```

Comment: PHP does have an `AND` operator - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php